# How to include an XML file into the root of a jar using Ant script?

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, build

I have the following problem with creating a .jar archive with Ant.

Into Eclipse I have a project named **AtmosAdampter** and I have the following Ant script that create an **atmosadapter.jar** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project default="default">

    <!-- ============================================ -->
    <!-- Load build properties                        -->
    <!-- ============================================ -->

    <property name="project.buildfile" value="../../../../../CrystalIceGUI/Project/build.num" />
    <property file="${project.buildfile}" />
    <property file="../../../../../CrystalIceGUI/Project/info.properties" />

    <!-- ============================================ -->
    <!-- Specify the classpath                        -->
    <!-- ============================================ -->

    <path id="project.classpath">
        <fileset dir="../../../../../SharedLib/">
            <include name="**/*.jar" />
        </fileset>
    </path>

    <!-- ============================================ -->
    <!-- The default target                           -->
    <!-- ============================================ -->

    <target name="default" depends="jar" />

    <!-- Elimina le cartelle contenenti le classi compilate ed i jar -->
    <target name="clean">
        <echo message="Into AtmosAdapter build.xml clean target" />
        <!-- <delete dir="../../Release" /> -->
        <delete file="../../Release/*.jar" />
        <!-- Elimina directory del jar finale -->
        <delete dir="bin" />
        <!-- Elimina directory delle classi compilate -->
    </target>

    <target name="compile" depends="clean">
        <echo message="Into AtmosAdapter build.xml compile target" />
        <mkdir dir="bin" />
        <javac srcdir="src" destdir="bin" classpathref="project.classpath" />
    </target>

    <target name="jar" description="Packs classes of AtmosAdapter" depends="compile">
        <jar destfile="../../Release/atmosadapter.jar" index="false">
            <fileset dir="bin" />
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Created-By" value="${info.software.author}" />
            </manifest>
        </jar>
    </target>

</project>
```

The problem is that, into Eclipse AtmosAdapter project, I have a **settings.xml** file into the **src** folder.

So, into Eclipse, the project have the following structure:

> AtmosAdapter ---> src ---> settings.xml

The problem is that using the previous Ant script I don't have the settings.xml file into the root of the.jar file.

What can I do to insert also this file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<jar>` task can take multiple `<fileset>`s:

```
<jar destfile="../../Release/atmosadapter.jar" index="false">
    <fileset dir="bin" />
    <fileset dir="src" includes="settings.xml" />
    <manifest>
        <attribute name="Created-By" value="${info.software.author}" />
    </manifest>
</jar>
```